# Using GlusterFS to store more than 10TB of data

Tags: linux, filesystems, glusterfs

I'm using Debian Buster on [Linode](https://www.linode.com/products/block-storage/) as a database/datastore server. Currently, it can only have 10TB per block storage mount, but I need more than that, **can GlusterFS be useful in this kind of scenario where I  need to build, say 100TB file mount** that I can mount also in multiple machines. Currently, Linode does not allow mounting the same network storage in multiple machines.

My plan is to run like 10 small CPU machines with each 10TB storage to build a 100TB distributed storage. **Is this the right approach?**

Comment: From this post it looks like it is possible: https://www.linode.com/community/questions/11292/could-gluster-fs-use-multiple-block-storage-volumes-on-one-machine

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work. GlusterFS Volume allows multiple clients/mounts connecting to same Volume.

**Note**: It will be Distribute volume without redundancy. If a node goes down then that means Partial data unavailability. Use Distributed Replicate in case redundancy is required.